# What stands p2v8 in mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8 for?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

After compiling a kernel for qemu, I get a lots of errors like listed below:

```
ipv6: version magic '3.18.11-hypriotos+ mod_unload modversions ARMv6 ' 
          should be '3.18.11-hypriotos+ mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8 '
```

Obviously my kernel and the Hypriotos kernel are somehow different. What means `p2v8`? And how can I enable it in my kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go and check out yourself in [arch/arm/include/asm/module.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/module.h?v=4.0#L32). It's added when `CONFIG_ARM_PATCH_PHYS_VIRT` is set. So you obviously need this config to be enabled. You can read the description of this option in [arch/arm/Kconfig](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/Kconfig?v=4.0#L232)

Keep in mind, however, that if you're not using the same kernel sources that were used for the main kernel build, you may encounter strange problems even if your module is successfully loaded.

Comment: Do you know where I find this in `menuconfig` ?

Comment: @mnhg: You can use search functionality in menuconfig to find this out (use `/` key). You will probably find that it cannot be found in any menu (there is no `Location:` section). It will, however, be selected automatically if particular conditions are met (sections `Depends on` and `Selected by`). The search result will show you which of the dependencies and `select by` conditions are met and which aren't. You have to tweak you're config until you get desired result.

Comment: This is automatically enabled by default if `CONFIG_EMBEDDED=y`. Probably your Hypriotos had this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define VERMAGIC_STRING                                                 \
    UTS_RELEASE "4.4.76 SMP mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8 " \
    MODULE_VERMAGIC_SMP MODULE_VERMAGIC_PREEMPT                     \
    MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODULE_UNLOAD MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODVERSIONS       \
    MODULE_ARCH_VERMAGIC
#endif
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.